# HTTPS but don't share certficate, manual installation required

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, https, openssl

Is it possible, from a server level (Apache), to enable HTTPS but that we don't share the certificate via the browser, the certificate must be installed prior to accessing HTTPS via the browser?

Best Regards

Anders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no. That's not how SSL works.

But really it would help if we knew what you were trying to achieve here. I suspect that you may be able to get your desired result using client side certificates and authenticating them on the server.

Comment: Ah, client side cert. is what it's called, that's it. I can take it from that point. Thanks.